# VBA copying cell value from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

does anyone has a clue how I can solve the following. I have a table in sheet 1 which I want to copy to sheet 2. However, copying will only take place for those cells in sheet1 for which column 3 row 11 to 32 are not empty. 
If say C11 is not empty, C11 will be copied together E11,F11,H11,I11 and J11. Then the code checks if C12 is filled and does the same and so on.

The copied cells are placed in sheet2 starting row and column 15. I have the following code which works very well. However it copies the formulas which obviously make no sense in sheet2, hence, values are nonsense:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
a = 15
For i = 11 To 32
If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Copy Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15)
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Copy Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 17)
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Copy Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 18)
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Copy Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 19)
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Copy Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 20)
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Copy Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 21)
a = a + 1
End If
Next i
```

How can I adjust the code in order to copy only the values?

Thank you very much for any support.

Comment: `.Cells(y, x)` represents a `Range` in VBA, and `Range` has a `.PasteSpecial` method. (Here's an MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx.) The option you're probably looking for here is `xlPasteValues`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be answered using the macro recorder and copy/paste values only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way to do this with minimal changes to your code would be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
a = 15
For i = 11 To 32
If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 15) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 17) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 18) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 19) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 20) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value
Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 21) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value
a = a + 1
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Wow. thanks for the quick reply. It works! Just another short question. This is obvioulsy linked to a button. How can I amend the code so whenever I press the button it first deletes everything in the respective columns and rows in sheet2 and then filles the values.

Comment: @user3849959 try recording a macro first. These questions can easily be answered with a little trial-and-error on your part...

Comment: For guys working with VBA continuously this "easily" might apply for beginners not. So please if you can help I'll appreciate if not just let others reply. Thanks!

Comment: @user3849959 I am in agreement with David that the proper commands for deletion can fairly easily be gotten from the Macro Recorder. If you are unaware of how to use the macro recorder. There are many resources available on the internet. It will help answer many basic how-to questions in VBA.

".ClearContents" is the command for deletion. To clear values, you would use that in place of " = Worksheets....Value" in the code which I have shown.

Comment: Do you know how to amend the code above so that in addition to the value when these are bold the copied values are bold as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rw As Range, rwD as Range

    Set rwD = Worksheets(2).Rows(15)

    For i = 11 To 32
        Set rw = Worksheets(1).Rows(i)
        If rw.Cells(3) <> "" Then

        rwD.Cells(15).Value = rw.Cells(3).Value
        rwD.Cells(17).Value = rw.Cells(5).Value
        rwD.Cells(18).Value = rw.Cells(6).Value
        rwD.Cells(19).Value = rw.Cells(7).Value
        rwD.Cells(20).Value = rw.Cells(8).Value
        rwD.Cells(21).Value = rw.Cells(9).Value

        Set rwD = rwD.Offset(1, 0)
        End If

    Next i
```